# Android from source compiling - whats wrong, why it doesn't work?

Tags: android, compilation, rom

Im trying to compile Resurrection Remix based on lolipop for my HTC Desire 620. I have downloaded RR sources, device, kernel and vendor also - github.com/bartek2017
My roomservice.xml
Code:

```
<manifest>
  <project name="bartek2017/android_kernel_htc_a31ul" path="kernel/htc/a31ul" remote="github" revision="cm-12.1" />
  <project name="HTC-MSM8916/android_device_htc_msm8916-common" path="device/htc/msm8916-common" remote="github" revision="cm-12.1" />
  <project name="bartek2017/android_device_htc_a31ul" path="device/htc/a31ul" remote="github" revision="cm-12.1" />
  <project name="bartek2017/proprietary_vendor_htc" path="vendor/htc/a31ul" remote="github" revision="master" />
</manifest>
```

Firstly after typing ". build/envsetup.sh" and "lunch" I don't see any option to choose RR for this HTC. I think it's probably because I havent created any file but I dont know what should be in "AndroidProducts.mk" and "vendorsetup.sh". Secondly I also dont know if I have to change anything in "device/htc/a31ul/" files like cm.mk or cmdependencies.mk?

When I create vendorsetup.sh inside htc/a31ul/

```
add_lunch_combo full_a31ul-user
add_lunch_combo full_a31ul-userdebug
add_lunch_combo full_a31ul-eng
```

I got error like below:

```
build/core/product_config.mk:234: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "full_a31ul". Stop.
Device a31ul not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository from CyanogenMod Github (http://github.com/CyanogenMod).
Repository for a31ul not found in the CyanogenMod Github repository list. If this is in error, you may need to manually add it to your local_manifests/roomservice.xml.
build/core/product_config.mk:234: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "full_a31ul". Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'full_a31ul'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

Oh and the problem with

```
build/core/product_config.mk:234: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "full_a31ul". Stop.
```

occurs even if I try compile rom for oneplus or samsung gt-i9300.

Im using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, openjdk 8.

I have no idea what to do now. I'll be thankful for any tip or tutorial.
Please, I really want to learn how to compile roms but Im stuck...

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am on the same page with you.

Comment: @Grief unfortunately no :( My question is still unsolved

Comment: For me, it helped to apply the same change for my device: https://github.com/ResurrectionRemix-Devices/android_device_oneplus_dumpling/commit/24557bafa207d245f8ebc1cf9bb9af793508343f

Comment: @Grief I'll check it one day, thanks for advice :) Currently I don't have any RR files.